# Use Paypal to accept payments in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout

Hi I want to use Paypal to accept payments in my applications. I feel like I'm going around in circles. What I have gathered is that there is very little documentation and a lot of marketing guff that you need to wade through - no disrespect to anyone who has worked on it.

I've learned that the Restful APIs from Paypal are not full featured yet, and the classic APIs provide a richer set of features - and my merchant account is in Australia so I don't think I can use REST APIs yet.

I've got a number of questions :

1. What do I need to get started ? Is it essentially formatting a payload according to the documents and calling a web service or is there more to it ?
2. Are there any sample .net applications that use the classic API. I may have missed something but GIT repository only seems to have REST api samples - should I get this and use classic in its place or is there more to it ?
3. Should I be using the SDK at all ? I checked in Nuget and there are a number of SDKs - the asp.net -http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal and it doesn't talk about the SDKs ??
4. If I am to get the SDK which one should I start with for Classic, I'm assuming I only need the SDK for the respective functions I need. For example there is a Merchant SDK and Payments Pro SDK which has the same information on www.paypal.com/SDK

What I want to be able to do is the following:

1. Accept Credit Card and Paypal payments on my wedapp
2. Do Adaptive Payments
3. Establish Recurring Payments after a Credit Card and Paypal Payment
4. Do PreApproval
5. Provide Express Checkout as per Paypal requirement

Please help, there appears to be a lack of getting started guides for Paypal and MVC. If anyone has any samples that would be fantastic!

Comment: Why is this getting marked down ?

Comment: Yeah why is it marked down?

Comment: you have to go with same approach but difference in web forms they are server side hidden fields and in mvc you will have html normal hidden fields

Comment: Whether it's the classic or REST API, your choice/flavor of ASP.Net wouldn't matter at all as far as PayPal API is concerned - the difference lies (as you already know) in how you'd implement said API or SDK (Web Forms, MVC, Web API, Web Pages, WCF, etc.). Correct AFAIK, for **direct credit card payments**, [REST API/SDK is only for US and UK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions)

Comment: Is there a sequence of the API Calls ? for example in the document for Authorize and Capture to perform the Authorize you need a Transaction ID which it states that it the number returned by Paypal. Where would I get this transaction number ? I thought DoAuthorize would be the first call ?

Comment: Your question is too broad - all of that is [documented by Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/) (Classic). Dev site has examples for REST as well.  e.g. `Auth` + `Capture`, vs `Sale` for `Paypal` payment vs `credit card payment`. You have to try and then come back with specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I can certainly help you with your **Express Checkout** requirement, and in shedding some light on the complexities of interfacing your application with PayPal.

[This .NET SDK](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.PaySharp) offers full support for **Express Checkout** functionality, as well as providing a concise readme that outlines how **Express Checkout** works at both high, and more precise levels of abstraction.

In terms of **Express Checkout**, there are 3 main terms that you should familiarise yourself with:

#### SetExpressCheckout

> Establishes a PayPal session based on Merchant credentials, and returns an Access Token pertaining to that session.

#### GetExpresscheckoutDetails

> Returns a definitive collection of metadata that describes the PayPal user (name, address, etc.).

#### DoExpressCheckoutPayment

> Collects the payment by transferring the transaction amount from the User's account to the Merchant account.